# Apache load balancer session creation error

Tags: apache-2.4, load-balancing

i've been trying to set up a load-balancer in apache; and i'm also pretty much a newbie for this stuff.

I am in a local network, and I have three PCs, one that I want to set up as a reverse proxy and two that are set up as nodes. All of them run Apache 2.4, windows 10 and php 7.3.6, and both of the nodes have their own copy of my PHP website and their own DB (both DBs replicate each other instantly, so the data is shared – also both nodes can be used stand-alone and reached by using their hostname or IP address)

As for the load balancer, it is up and running, but it does not work: the site is served and it switches in between nodes based on the load, but it does not create a session correctly, thus not allowing even to log-in into the site.
If the site is accessed through the load balancer and not directly thru typing one of the nodes’s name (because otherwise it works) it does not create a session correctly.

It seems that the load balancer cannot create a proper PHPSESSID session cookie - and only when two or more nodes are present, because if only one node remains because the other one is unavailable, the load balancer works and the session is created correctly.
And I think that a session cookie *does* get created – albeit incorrectly.
(I supposed that since the new user page is programmed to redirect to the index page in case it detects a logged user.. and the index page is programmed to boot a user back to the login page if it detects invalid permissions in the session cookie.
I have tried to mess with the Apache httpd.conf file in order to fix this, but to no avail; and as for the practical things I tried (I do not guarantee that they were applied correctly, since I am very much a novice in this field). For all of these tested I disabled every access control (i.e. anyone can access the proxy):

1) I tried to use ProxyPass with the stickysession attribute, as described in this link: [Apache2 Loadbalancer with sticky session only sticky for GET, not POST](https://serverfault.com/questions/949169/apache2-loadbalancer-with-sticky-session-only-sticky-for-get-not-post)

2) I tried to use the ProxyPassReverseCookiePath and ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain directives, as described in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676890/apache-proxypass-and-sessions

This is how the relevant .conf part looks like (I have commented all of the directives that I tried but did not work):

```
ProxyRequests Off
#Header add Set-Cookie " PHPSESSID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED

<Proxy *>
#here there would be IP filtering, which I removed altogether for ease
</Proxy>

<Proxy balancer://myset>
    BalancerMember "http://192.168.3.202:80" route=route1
    BalancerMember "http://192.168.3.203:85" route=route2
    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
    #ProxySet stickysession= PHPSESSID
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
ProxyPass "/"  "balancer://myset/"
ProxyPassReverse "/"  "balancer://myset/"
#ProxyPassReverseCookiePath "balancer://myset/" "/"
#ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain "balancer://myset/" localhost
#ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain "balancer://myset/" "/”
```

Anyone has any idea on why the load balancer does not correctly create sessions?

Comment: I have briefly tested this setup on Apache 2.4.29 with just dummy reflector backends with socat. I think where you go wrong is that you try to set PHPSESSID with the balancer. You should leave that to PHP itself. For the balancer set a cookie with a name like balancer-route or something and use that in the stickysession setting. Of course the client can just play with those cookies, but if you leave them alone it should work.

Comment: thanks very much for the answer, it should be working perfectly (i can actually log into my site right now!). i'll have to test all the functionalities more thoroughly, but this is a major step foward, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sticky balancer sessions work but have to use their own cookie. PHPSESSID should be handled by PHP.

For the balancer set a cookie with a name like balancer-route or something and use that in the stickysession setting. Of course the client can just play with those cookies, but if you leave them alone it should work.

Another consideration is that this does not cover the case of balancer nodes going down and up. The balancer will just send a new route where there is no PHP session stored, so a new PHPSESSID will be generated.

In this case you should really store the PHP session in the database, since you already replicate that. I would not advise trying to replicate PHP session files because they do not flush constantly, so do not reflect the in memory session. Of course some php database driven applications already store their sessions in their own database.

Some pointers for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36753514/2824577

Or you setup redis: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-redis-server-as-a-session-handler-for-php-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

> I have briefly tested this setup on Apache 2.4.29 with just dummy
>   reflector backends with socat. I think where you go wrong is that you
>   try to set PHPSESSID with the balancer. You should leave that to PHP
>   itself. For the balancer set a cookie with a name like balancer-route
>   or something and use that in the stickysession setting. Of course the
>   client can just play with those cookies, but if you leave them alone
>   it should work. – user188737

This solved my question, thanks to the commenter (too bad that i can't mark the comment directly as the answer)!